# 3D face scan direct to COVID-19 mask (N95)

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have been working with Chief of Staff at Cedar Park Regional Hospital to make the Montana Mask(https://longliveyoursmile.com/3d-printable-mask-for-covid-19/).  This mask works fairly well, except that it doesn't fit everyone.  I have used the face scanning app from Bellus3D to generate an STL file.  I imported it into Solidworks and can make a mask tailored to an individual.

This does not scale.

Does someone have the ability to make a phone app almost exactly like the Bellus3D app, but instead of emailing an STL of the face, have it email an STL of the mask?  That file could then be sent to any printer, and the filter element and other parts are standard and can be kept in stock on premise.

I have contacted Bellus3D, but it's a web form and I don't know when or if they will return my request for info.

I can provide files for the filter side of the mask, and other assistance that will aid in 3D printing.

Comment: Despite this being a worthy cause I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about using Blender.

Comment: Where is a more appropriate forum to reach users that are knowledgeable in acquiring meshes and merging them?  The fact that it's an app is secondary.  Yeah, it may not be Blender specific.

Comment: CGSociety, Polycount Forum, Blender Artists Community, Reddit..etc. BSE is not for these kind of requisition, sorry about that